# how to show pop up alert message without blocking the page to render and how to refresh chart in each 30 sec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, fusioncharts

i want to show pop up if value is less than 3 . i used alert function but when this alert event is fired page is not rendering. how to show popup without blocking the page to display , and how to refresh the chart every 30 sec.

```
<script>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            LoadChart();
        });
        function LoadChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("get", "air")',//remote api address

                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {

                        var dust= data.sensorsdata.cl;
                        if (dust > 3)
                            alert("dust is high");
                        $("#lblDate").text(data.sensorsdata.CurrentTime);
                        $("#currenttime").show();

                     var dustchart= new FusionCharts({
                            type: 'angulargauge',
                            renderAt: 'ph-container',
                            width: '450',
                            height: '300',
                            dataFormat: 'json',
                            dataSource: {
                                "chart": {
                                    "caption": "Chlorine ",
                                    "lowerLimit": "0",
                                    "upperLimit": "14",
                                    "showValue": "1",
                                    "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                                    "theme": "fint"
                                },
                                "colorRange": {
                                    "color": [{
                                        "minValue": "0",
                                        "maxValue": "5",
                                        "code": "#6baa01"
                                    }, {
                                        "minValue": "5",
                                        "maxValue": "10",
                                        "code": "#f8bd19"
                                    }, {
                                        "minValue": "10",
                                        "maxValue": "14",
                                        "code": "#e44a00"
                                    }]
                                },
                                "dials": {
                                    "dial": [{
                                        "value": dust
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        dustchart.render();


                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>


 <td><div id="dust-container" style="float:left;"></div></td>
```

Comment: [angular-toastr](https://foxandxss.github.io/angular-toastr/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript modals will always block page. You need to implement your own popup code or use library for example bootstrap modal

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Another way you can think of if you are doing just simple notifications is using something called toastr (or growl) - there are libs for this also.

For updating fussioncharts look at this example

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-javascript-libraries/jquery/updating-chart-properties-using-jquery.html#changing-the-data-for-an-existing-chart

Comment: and how to refresh chart in every 30 sec.